# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined

Tags: html, angular

I have a json file that comes like this

```
{
  "report": {
    "description": "Average of the quantity of items per person (total and just non-infected)",
    "average_items_quantity_per_person": 164.7473903966597,
    "average_items_quantity_per_healthy_person": 172.29787234042553
   }
}
```

my report.model.ts

```
export class Report{
constructor(    
    public description: string,
    public average_items_quantity_per_person: number,
    public average_items_quantity_per_healthy_person: number
){}
}
```

my report.component.ts

[image: ERRO]
but whenever I try to call in the HTML file

```
{{printa(report)}}
```

I get this error

[image: ERRO]
Does anyone know what this error is, or if I am related to the JSON file with the .model correctly

Comment: show your report.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass reports since you are assigning the data to the variable reports,

```
{{printa(reports)}}
```

or you can directly print the description field as,

```
console.log(this.reports.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `printa(report)` was a typo and you do in fact have `printa(reports)`, you're getting this error because Angular is calling this function before your reports service sets the data. Since `reports` is `undefined` before the first `subscribe` callback is called, it is calling `printa(undefined)` and then trying to access `undefined.description` on line 25.

There are two ways you could fix this. Either initialize your `reports` member to contain an empty `description` property like

```
public reports: Report = {
    description: '',
    average_items_quantity_per_person: NaN,
    average_items_quantity_per_healthy_person: NaN,
};
```

or add a check to `printa` to return if `r` is `undefined` like

```
public printa(r: Report) {
    if (!r) { return; }

    console.log(r.description);
}
```